# Upload videos to Youtube from Android app

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have to develop an Android application that uploads videos to Youtube without using [ytd-android](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/).Is there any sample code to post the request?I have searched a lot and everything found was done using [ytd-android](http://code.google.com/p/ytd-android/).Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube provides a [REST API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started), and good documentation with examples. Start reading the basic concepts like authorization and authentication, at the beginning at least, then move to more specific topics.

Here's the page dedicated to [uploading videos to Youtube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos).

Comment: I got the access token but I want to know how to post a request for uploading video.Any sample code?

Comment: Browse the Uploading Videos chapter, there you'll find sample code.